# Use more than one Parsley Field instance on 'parsley:field:success'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

I'm trying to remove a validation message on a form when two specific fields have been validated.

I can do it when one field is successfully validated but how would I go about doing it when multiple fields (or perhaps even a group) have been validated?

Below is what I'm trying to accomplish

```
$.listen('parsley:field:success', function (parsleyField) {
    if ((parsleyField.$element.attr('name') == 'field1')) && ((parsleyField.$element.attr('name') == 'field2')){
        $(".tab-nav-1").removeClass("tab-validation-error")
    }
});
```

Is there a way to perform some action when a group of fields is validated (even if the form isn't)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work since `parsleyField` is associated to only one field. That is, if you have a form with two (valid) inputs, that function will be executed one time for each input.

*Updated solution*

Looking at [Parsley's events](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events) turns out you can use `parsley:form:validated` which is triggered after the form validation is performed. The use of this event simplifies the solution quite a bit because you can simply check if the inputs are valid. Here's the code you need ([**jsfiddle available**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/kL1dcrgc/1/)):

```
$.listen('parsley:form:validated', function (parsleyForm) {
    var isValidField1 = $("input[name=field1]").parsley().isValid(),
        isValidField2 = $("input[name=field2]").parsley().isValid();

    if (isValidField1 && isValidField2) {
        $(".tab-nav-1").removeClass("tab-validation-error");
    } else {
        $(".tab-nav-1").addClass("tab-validation-error");
    }
});
```

---

*Original solution*

You could create an array to store the input fields and remove them if they became invalid. Then, each time you perform a validation, just check if the fields exist in the array and, if so, remove the class. Otherwise, add the class.

Admittedly the solution is not as straight forward as one would like. Take the look at the following code ([**jsfiddle available**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/a0sc5osL/))

```
// this will store our valid fields
var validFields = [];

$("form").parsley();

// whenever a field is valid
$.listen('parsley:field:success', function (parsleyField) {
    // add this field's name to the array
    addToArray(parsleyField.$element.attr('name'));

    // Do we have both fields within the array?
    if ($.inArray('field1', validFields) != -1 && $.inArray('field2', validFields) != -1) {
        // If so, remove the class
        $(".tab-nav-1").removeClass("tab-validation-error");
    } else {
        // Otherwise, add the class. There could be a time 
        $(".tab-nav-1").addClass("tab-validation-error");
    }
});

// Whenever an error occurs, lets remove the field from the array
$.listen('parsley:field:error', function (parsleyField) {
    removeFromArray(parsleyField.$element.attr('name'));
});

/**
 * Adds a string to an array
 */
function addToArray(fieldName) {
    // For our case, we're just adding the value if it matches our fields
    if ($.inArray(fieldName, validFields) === -1 && (fieldName == 'field1' || fieldName == 'field2')) {
        validFields.push(fieldName);
    }
}

/**
 * Removes a string from an array
 */
function removeFromArray(fieldName) {
    // For this case, we discard the fields that don't match the fields we need
    if (fieldName != 'field1' && fieldName != 'field2')
        return;

    // So, add the field if it doesn't exist in the array
    if ($.inArray(fieldName, validFields) != -1) {
        for(var i = validFields.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            validFields.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, that's a lot more complex than i thought this would be! but I really appreciate the detailed answer with jsfiddle and it works perfectly :) thanks

Comment: @jesusthatsgreat I've found another (better) way of accomplish that. Take a look at the updated answer

Comment: i actually need to remove the validation message in real time / as soon as both fields are validated so the first solution is still my preferred option but this is definitely a cleaner solution which I can hopefully use at a later date!

Comment: @jesusthatsgreat I see what you mean. Yeah, only the first solution works in that case.